# SELECT in cascaded AFTER DELETE trigger returning stale data in Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have an `AFTER INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` trigger function which runs after any change to table `campaigns` and triggers an update on table `contracts`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_campaign_target() RETURNS trigger AS $update_campaign_target$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE contracts SET updated_at = now() WHERE contracts.contract_id = NEW.contract_id;
    END;
$update_campaign_target$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_campaign_target ON campaigns;
CREATE TRIGGER update_campaign_target AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON campaigns
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_campaign_target();
```

I have another trigger on table `contracts` that runs `BEFORE UPDATE`. The goal is to generate a computed column `target` which displays either `contracts.manual_target` (if set) or `SUM(campaigns.target) WHERE campaign.contract_id = NEW.contract_id`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_contract_manual_target() RETURNS trigger AS $update_contract_manual_target$
    DECLARE
        campaign_target_count int;
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.manual_target IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            NEW.target := NEW.manual_target;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSE
            SELECT SUM(campaigns.target) INTO campaign_target_count
                FROM campaigns
                WHERE campaigns.contract_id = NEW.contract_id;
            NEW.target := campaign_target_count;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
    END;
$update_contract_manual_target$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_contract_manual_target ON contracts;
CREATE TRIGGER update_contract_manual_target BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON contracts
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_contract_manual_target();
```

This works as expected on INSERT and UPDATE on `campaigns`, but does not work on DELETE. When a campaign is deleted, the result of `SUM(campaigns.target)` in the second trigger includes the deleted campaign's target, and thus does not update the `contracts.target` column to the expected value. A second update of `contracts` will correctly set the value.

Three questions:

1. Why doesn't this work?
2. Is there a way to achieve the behavior I'm looking for using triggers?
3. For this type of data synchronization, is it better to achieve this using triggers or views? Triggers make sense to me because this is a table that we will read many magnitudes of times more than we'll write to it, but I'm not sure what the best practices are.

Comment: I think you are missing a `RETURN` clause on the first trigger,
 `RETURN NEW;` --after the UPDATE clause

Comment: The reason `Delete` fails to produce the expected outcome is that there is no `new` record, all columns (new.column_name) are NULL.   See [Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) documentation for how to handle this, As far as View vs. Trigger, I *tend to  always* choose View if possible. However, since you are changing the data values (before trigger) and introducing data (after trigger) a view is not possible. But it has nothing to do with the number of selects.

Comment: > I think you are missing a RETURN clause on the first trigger, RETURN NEW; --after the UPDATE clause <

I don't think that's necessary for an AFTER trigger: 

"The return value is ignored for row-level triggers fired after an operation, and so they can return NULL."

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/trigger-definition.html

Comment: > The reason Delete fails to produce the expected outcome is that there is no new record, all columns (new.column_name) are NULL.  <

Ah, yep this is probably right. I need to use OLD.contract_id if it's a DELETE. I'll try this now.

Comment: @AnthonySotolongo you'e partly right though, there's no implicit return so I need to RETURN NULL;

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is the usage of `NEW.contract_id` in the `AFTER DELETE` trigger:

```
UPDATE contracts SET updated_at = now() WHERE contracts.contract_id = NEW.contract_id;
```

Per the [Triggers on Data Changes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) documentation, NEW is NULL for DELETE triggers.

Updating the code to use OLD instead of NEW fixes the issue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_campaign_target() RETURNS trigger AS $update_campaign_target$
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'DELETE'
        THEN
            UPDATE contracts SET updated_at = now() WHERE contracts.contract_id = OLD.contract_id;
        ELSE
            UPDATE contracts SET updated_at = now() WHERE contracts.contract_id = NEW.contract_id;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$update_campaign_target$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Thanks to [Anthony Sotolongo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8308381/anthony-sotolongo) and [Belayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7623856/belayer) for your help!